# I am coding a student grade tracker and can not figure out how to add student to the database

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

The project I am working on is a student grade tracker for CSI101, but am struggling with one key part. I have the database working, the webpage up and running. When I add a variable (i.e Student Name) from the database directly it saves, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to add it by just by entering it into the fields designated on the website because they dont work.

```
if (menuOption == "Report"):
    try: 
      firstName = formData["firstName"].value + "%"
    except: 
      firstName = "%"
    try: 
      lastName = formData["lastName"].value + "%"
    except: 
      lastName = "%"


    print("Location:simpleReport.py?firstName=\"" + firstName + "\"&lastName=\""    +         lastName + "\"")
    print()
```

the above code works the way it should to show a full report, however the below code is what I need to allow me to add the student data

```
elif (menuOption == "Modify Student"):

    try: 
      firstName = formData["firstName"].value + "%"
    except: 
      firstName = "%"
    try: 
      lastName = formData["lastName"].value + "%"
    except: 
      lastName = "%"
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hey Steven. it's not super clear from the info above what you're asking for. does any of your code there talk to a database? what errors do you get?

Comment: yes the code above everything that I put in there connects it to my database. 
I guess my real question is, what string of code should I be using to add a set of group of variables into the database.

Premature end of script headers: menuHandler.py, referer: http://34.193.0.192/cgi-bin/menu.py is the error code i am recieving

Answer (score 0):

For python2.x to connect mysql you can use MySQLdb, for python3.x use pymysql instead.
For example:

```
conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='***',db='student',port=3306,charset='utf8')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from student')
data=cur.fetchall()
```